# using console input correctly

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I'm new to C# and was wondering if someone could help me.
What I'm trying is writing only the integer of the console input to the memory of the game.
Atm the problem is that it tries to write "/fov "+int which isnt working.

here is my code

```
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if (input.ToLower().Equals("/fov ") && number >= 10 && number <= 150)
    {
            m.WriteMemory("game.exe+0x176DCF", "bytes", "0x90 0x90 0x90");
            m.WriteMemory("game.exe+0x176BC9", "bytes", "0x90 0x90 0x90");
            m.WriteMemory("game.exe+0x00DB80E4,0x40,0x18", "Int", "" +number);
    }
```

Comment: What is the user input? Is "/fov someInteger" on one line or is there an enter press after "/fov"?

Comment: At the moment it waits for some input and after your press enter it waits for second input. To pass you conditional statement you should write "/fov " -< witch space Then press Enter and then program waits for integer input. I assume you want it to work with "/fov <integer>" ? If so - you should ask for user input only once and then parse this string

Comment: Can you define "which isn't working"?  Are you getting an exception on the `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())` statement?  In general, just believing that a user will enter the correct text is a bad idea.  Using `int.TryParse` will let you evaluate whether the entered data is, in fact, an integer in the correct format

Comment: "/fov someInteger" should be on one line yea

Comment: if I use "int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());" it gives me the error: The input string is in the wrong format

Comment: So, what you are saying is that you expect your user to enter the following on a single line: `/fov 999` (where `999` represents any integer between 10 and 150).  Is that correct?

Comment: yea thats correct. I'm testing your answer right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const string fovPattern = @"/fov\s+(\d{2,3})";
Regex fovRegex = new Regex(fovPattern);
var entered = Console.ReadLine();
if (fovRegex.IsMatch(entered))
{
    var groups = fovRegex.Match(entered).Groups;
    if (groups.Count < 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This shouldn't happen");
    }
    if (int.TryParse(fovRegex.Match(entered).Groups[1].ToString(), out var numEntered) &&
        numEntered >= 10 && numEntered <= 150)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"We are all set FOV value is {numEntered}");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something's wrong");
    }
}
```

That pattern at the beginning is called a regular expression.  It says "I expect to see a string that starts with `/fov`, followed by one or more whitespace characters followed by two or three numeric digits."  The parentheses `()` around the `\d{2,3}` establishes the number part as a group that I can address specifically.

Then I check to see if the entered string matches that pattern.  If it does, then I go and fetch the second group (the first group (`group[0]`) matches the entire string, the second (`group[1]`) matches the digits).

If there are at least two groups (I can't imagine why there wouldn't be, but, just in case), I parse that second group into a number.  If it's an integer between 10 and 150, then all is good

Comment: I used your code and added my adresses in. The weird thing is, nothing happends ingame. I know that the adresses work, but its not writing anything to memory it seems like.

Comment: nvm. my bad. I had to restart the game. Now it works

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

Have you tried using `Int32.Parse()` method?

Replace the line

`int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`

with

`int number = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine())`

Hope it works! Tell us if you have more problems :)

Comment: In general, using `int.TryParse` is just about always better than `int.Parse` when dealing with user entered strings.

Comment: True, better idea for dealing with possible problems. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: To elaborate on Flydog57's answer, `int.Parse()` with throw an exception if the input is not a valid integer. `int.TryParse()` will not throw an exception and it returns a bool to let you know if the parse succeed. While the same behavior can be accomplished by putting `int.Parse()` inside a try catch block, this is considered bad practice as try-catch blocks shouldn't be used to control program flow where it is avoidable.

Comment: @Delunado how this could be an answer for the question above? I don't think he encountered problems with parsing integer input